# Type code in to a text input form, how?

Tags: php, forms, upload, scripting, input

i have this image upload script.

```
 <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
          if (isset ($_FILES['new_image'])){
              $imagename = $_FILES['new_image']['name'];
              $source = $_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name'];
              $target = "temporary_images/".$imagename;
              move_uploaded_file($source, $target);

              $imagepath = $imagename;
              $save = "temporary_images/" . $imagepath; //This is the new file you saving
              $file = "temporary_images/" . $imagepath; //This is the original file

              list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file) ; 

              $modwidth = 350;                         
              $modheight = 100; 

              $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight) ; 
              $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ; 
              imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height) ; 

              imagejpeg($tn, $save, 100) ; 

              $save = "temporary_images/sml_" . $imagepath; //This is the new file you saving
              $file = "temporary_images/" . $imagepath; //This is the original file

              list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file) ; 

              $modwidth = 80; 
              $modheight = 100; 

              $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight) ; 
              $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ; 
              imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height) ; 

              imagejpeg($tn, $save, 100) ; 
            echo "Large image: <img src='temporary_images/".$imagepath."'><br>"; 
          }
        }
```

I need the script to write the name of the file in the form

```
<form> 
 <input name="animeinput" id="animeinput" size="20" class="textbox"> 
</form>
```

So basically i need my upload script to write $imagepath (the filename that is used for storing the image) into the form when an image has been uploaded.

How do i do this?

Comment: So, you submit the form (which uploads the image), which takes you to another page. Do you want the filename that is used for storing the image to be displayed on the new page?

Comment: This was asked a few hours ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321256/type-code-in-to-a-text-input-form-how/

Comment: If you're not getting the answers you want, try rephrasing the question or being more specific (as @JorenB's comment was trying to extract)

Comment: @David Archer, the people did not quite understand what i meant, thats why i had to make a new one and make a better explanation.

Comment: Oh, there is an edit button. Didnt see that before.

Comment: Ok, so is the html markup in the same file as the upload script, or in a separate file? If separate, is it in included php file or an html file processed by a template engine. Is it the same form displaying now with an image, or a new form?

Comment: The html markup is in the same file.

Comment: In which case @TomHaigh's answer should do the trick.  Directly after your echo line, close the php tag "?>", add his code then reopen the php tag "<?php".  My answer would work too, though his is the neater way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to add to your script, which you previously mentioned is displaying the image, then is this what you mean?

```
...
echo "Large image: <img src='temporary_images/".$imagepath."'><br>"; 
echo "<form>";
echo '<input type="text" value="' . $imagePath . '" name="animeinput" id="animeinput" size="20" class="textbox">'; 
echo "</form>";
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you mean, but this should work:

```
<form> 
 <input value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($imagepath); ?>" name="animeinput" id="animeinput" size="20" class="textbox"> 
</form>
```